# How to change UserLockoutEnabledByDefault and DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan In ASP MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to let the administrator to be able to change DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan and UserLockoutEnabledByDefault of users accounts

Basically when the application is launched the default values of the Identidy.cs are

```
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
```

Now in the administration controller , I would like to allowe admins to change those values

so I have created an action result

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ChangeDefaultUserLockingSetting(int PasswordAttempts, int DefaultLockingTime)
        {

            UserManager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(DefaultLockingTime);
            UserManager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = PasswordAttempts;

            return View("Index", loadAdministrationViewModel());
        }
```

Now in the admin html , I have a form :

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeDefaultUserLockingSetting", "Administration", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
    { 
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PasswordAttempts)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DefaultLockingTime)

        <input type="submit" value="Submit strongly type synchronous form" />
    }
```

But when the values are passed by the form and the action result is triggered , the default values are not overrides nor changed, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the model you're using strongly typed model, but why in controller action method seems that you want to use named arguments instead of using passed model from view? Can you check values for `PasswordAttempts` & `DefaultLockingTime` during POST to `ChangeDefaultUserLockingSetting` action?

Comment: If the default in Identity.cs still remains **manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);**, why do you expect to have different results?

Comment: @AlfMoh I just don't know how to make a way to make this values be changed , I want them to be overrided

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto The named argument are in the identidy.cs . The value passed from model are in the admin controller ....I'm just trying to figure out a way to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up resolving my own problem by

Creating table in the database reserved for session settings

and when the application run all what I did is read them :

```
    manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = AccountSettings.getUserlock();
    manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = AccountSettings.getLockOutTime();
    manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = AccountSettings.getMaxFailedAccount();
```